# Open With to Save As

Tags: applications, internal-storage

Does anyone know of an Android app that shows up in the 'Open With' dialog for any file type and allows me to save the file to local storage? For example: when I open an Google Inbox PDF attachment I only find my pdf reading apps but there is no option to save the file

Comment: Do you strictly want the application in order to save Gmail attachments or any other files types?

Comment: A generic app that could handle any filetype (and so shows up in any Open With dialog) would be the best, but the idea came from the fact that I am unable to save pdf attachments from Inbox and would be a solution for now

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I use a file manager called ES Explorer which happens to have that intergration, esp when you choose the share via button.

Take a look:

[image: Save to]